# Electrical receptacle grounding

Tags: electrical, receptacle

my name is Mike. I have installed L.E.D. Lights in my customers garden room. She called me to say she was having a problem with the lights not going all the way off. When I asked her what she meant, she said you could see very dim light coming from 2 or 3 diodes?

I went over the next day to see if the outlet was grounded and it was. Now having said all this,I am the tile man, but agreed to install the lights to get the job. It would appear that there is trace voltage coming threw the line.i am not and electrician, but I would like to get this job done. Can someone please help me to understand what I need

Comment: Are the lights on a dimmer?

Comment: Hey Dan, they are a pr. Of L.E.D. Lights plugged into a timer and then to the wall.  Mike

Comment: Odds are the timer is designed for incandescent lights and is wired without a neutral wire. These work (when off) by trickling a small current through the load. This does not produce visible light with incandescent lights because the current is too low. However, LEDs are more sensative. Using this timer with LEDs may shorten the life of the LEDs or the timer.

Comment: Hey Doxylover, thanks for that info. Someone had told me that I should put a relay on it. Sounded like Greek to me. Lol. Do they make a timer for LED's? Thanks Mike

Comment: You need a timer designed for non-incandescent loads. Almost any that has a neutral wire, in addition to the hot, load and ground wires. However, this will only work if there is a neutral available in the box. Unfortunately, there is a good chance there isn't one. In this case, assuming you aren't running new wiring, you really only can replace the timer with a switch or remove the LEDs.

Comment: Thank you Doxylover, I appreciate your time and info. Mike